# issue with addOnCompleteListener solved! -> running into W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with my android app that it won't compile due to an issue with OnCompleteListener. The specific error that I am getting is

error: no suitable method found for addOnCompleteListener(,<anonymous OnCompleteListener>)
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
^
method Task.addOnCompleteListener(Executor,OnCompleteListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to Executor)
method Task.addOnCompleteListener(Activity,OnCompleteListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to Activity)

I am doing a user authentication system with my android app but for some reason whenever I compile the app I run into this error. I am following this resource (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) from Android Studios. Any help would be immensely appreciated to get my user authentication to work and be correctly populated on my Firebase.

Thank you so much in advance!

```html
package com.example.hoptoit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private boolean permissionDenied = false;
    private LatLng Hopkins = new LatLng(39.33033283923643, -76.62053915767162);

    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Button buttonSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp);
        EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        TextView textViewResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse);

        editTextEmail.setText("");
        editTextPassword.setText("");

        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            updateUI(currentUser);
        }




        buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextPassword.toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextEmail.toString())) {
                    textViewResponse.setText("Email Address or Password is not provided");
                } else {


                    System.out.println("This is blank maybe " + editTextEmail.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("This is blank maybe " + editTextPassword.getText().toString());

                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                        //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                        updateUI(user);
                                    } else {
                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                       // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                       // Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                                //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        updateUI(null);
                                    }
                                }
                            });



                }

            }
        });






    };

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    }

    

}
```

Thank to someone's previous comment, my app is finally able to compile but for some reason when a user enters a username and password, the terminal tells me
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I believe I connected my Firebase throughout and enabled Email authentication so let me know what other steps I could be missing, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `this` from inside an `onClickListener()` which isn't going to return the Context you're most likely looking for as the parameter for your `addOnCompleteListener`.

You can use the Activity name to specify that you're looking for the Context:

```
// Replace 'this' with 'YourActivityName.this'
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString())
    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Sammy Thank you so much, that fixed the issue! but for some reason, now that I am able to compile my app, I get a result of W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.? Do you know how to fix this? I am connected to the FireBase and I enabled authentication and added the proper dependencies to the Gradle, I have not specified my app's  SHA-1 fingerprint since I am unsure how to do that. Would you know how to fix this issue to complete the authentication?

Comment: You're welcome, @fabiocontreras. I have some guesses as to why you might be seeing that warning. However, you should create a new post with that issue to maintain the individual question and answer format of stackoverflow. And please remember to mark the answer as accepted to update this question as solved.